# TableLayout ScrollView Vertical & Horizontal

Tags: android, scrollbar

How we can setup `ScrollView` vertically & horizontally? I tried the below code, but it didn't work.

```
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/red"
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
 android:scrollbarSize="12dip" >

   <HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:collapseColumns="2"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >
    </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ScrollView >
</ScrollView>
```

Here is all my code : http://pastebin.com/ysRhLMyt

Current screen :

[image]

I want to display scroll bar always.

Comment: May be this link useful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/problem-in-horizontal-scroll-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

- Set the android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"

  ```
             OR
  ```
- ScrollView1.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

  ```
             OR
  ```
- android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" **and**

  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" for vertical

  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" for horizontal

And one more thing,

Remember, the ScrollView can have only one child control, so we can make a container (Linear, relative, Table Layouts) the child of the ScrollView and put all the controls inside this child.

For reference: http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-scrollview.html

Comment: This is showing Scroll-bar with `android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"` option.I couldn't drag the bar.I tried on emulator.I will try on device & let you know

Answer (score 1):

Nested scroll views doesn't work. It's related to scroll view touch handling: top level view always consume all touch events. You have to write you own custom scroll view.

Comment: How we can define custom scroll view?

Comment: There is no quick recipe. Subclass from ViewGroup and implement all the stuff. You can grab android ScrollView sources and check how it is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `android:orientation` attribute. This can be used for horizontal or vertical: `android:orientation="horizontal"` or `android:orientation="vertical"`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
      android:scrollbarSize="12dip"
      android:background="@color/red" 
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:stretchColumns="1" 
            android:collapseColumns="2">
      </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code which makes horizontal and vertical scroll view,
To see its effect first define a area around *200x 200 dp* and paste this code inside it.

The View will scrolling horizontally as well as vertically.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```