# How to build a multiple columns ListView in Android and user can scroll to see invisible columns?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to build a Table with many columns (20) and many rows (100), so some columns would be invisible due to the screen's width.

I choose to use ListView for this, but how to make user see the invisible columns, I'd like the table fix the first column, and user can horizontally scroll the other columns in this listview.

is there any 3rd lib for this? How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use a `TableLayout` with vertical and horizontal scrolling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266787/tablelayout-scrollview-vertical-horizontal

Comment: TableLayout is not good, if we have too many rows, it eats too much memory.

Comment: What about ViewPager? Each column can be a list view in a fragment (so you see only a column per screen) and you can go to side columns through sliding to right or left.
I've implemented something like that in something like a supermarket app: you have departments (columns) and a list of products per department. Sliding to the sides gave to users a shortcut to another departments as if they were 'walking' in a real world supermarket.